# How to handle duplicate entries in Coredata with Codable

Tags: ios, swift, codable

This `init` function inserts a new entity every time, even if the `user_id` is same.

How can I solve this? I want each entity to just be only one with the user_id.

My code is like this:

```
public convenience init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
    // Create NSEntityDescription with NSManagedObjectContext
    guard let contextUserInfoKey = CodingUserInfoKey.managedContext,
        let managedObjectContext = decoder.userInfo[contextUserInfoKey] as? NSManagedObjectContext,
        let entity = NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: "User", in: managedObjectContext) else {
            fatalError("Failed to decode User!")
    }
    self.init(entity: entity, insertInto: managedObjectContext)

    let userInfo = try decoder.container(keyedBy: UserInfoKeys.self)
    username = try userInfo.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .username)
    user_id = try userInfo.decode(String.self, forKey: .user_id)
}
```

Comment: Why are you using `Codable`?  You will need to query CoreData first to see if an object already exists with the specified user id

Comment: Yeah, I knew that. I just think the Codable is easy way to parse json data. So, is there any way to do that?

Comment: Ok, If you are parsing JSON, that makes sense.  That wasn't clear from your question.  You need to use an `NSFetchRequest` to search for existing users. I suspect that an initialiser isn't a good pattern to use for this.  Personally I would use a static (class) factory method that returns an optional `User`

Comment: @EvilHydra  Did you find out how to solve this?  I'm struggling with this too!!!

Comment: @Vish_iOS No, I did not solve this. I do check duplicate entity before it init now.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue as well, my solution is basically to perform a duplicate check before any `init` gets called, use a conditional statement to `init` it in 2 ways depending on whether the duplicate is found or not. Here is my solution:

```swift
import Foundation
import CoreData

@objc(MyItem)
public class MyItem: NSManagedObject, Decodable {
    private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case id, value
    }

    required convenience public init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        guard let context = decoder.userInfo[.managedObjectContext] as? NSManagedObjectContext else {
            throw DecoderConfigurationError.missingManagedObjectContext
        }
        
        /// Check if a duplicate exists before the init
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        let id = try container.decode(UUID.self, forKey: .id)
        let fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<MyItem> = MyItem.fetchRequest()
        fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "id == %@", id as CVarArg)

        /// If duplicate is found, we insert it into nothing (nil)
        let existingItems = try context.fetch(fetchRequest)
        if let existingItem = existingItems.first {
            self.init(entity: .entity(forEntityName: "MyItem", in: context)!, insertInto: nil)
        } 
        
        /// Otherwise, we insert it into the current context
        else {
            self.init(context: context)
        }
    }
}
```